# Map JSONArray to object by position

Tags: java, json, gson

In an API I'm working with I receive a certain part as a plain JSON array instead of a normal key => value pair. Its stupid, but that's what I have to deal with.

Example:

```
{"build":29625,"list": [
   [312218505,1000,624437010,21997878697,35228,0,0,0],
   [186873474,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0]
   ...
]}
```

The problem is getting Google GSON to map each array position to a field in a normal Object. Since unsurprisingly there isn't any native support for this I've had to roll my own solution: Each "request" that needs conversion implements a CustomConvert interface which has `convertToObjects()` and `convertToJson()` methods. Each "entry" has a bunch of fields with a `@ArrayPosition(number)` annotation. The convert methods translate between the two lists.

As this is ugly, is there a better way to do this with Google GSON or even another JSON library for Java?

Comment: Erm, write a gson serializer/deserializer? Can you give an example of the JSON you are receiving?

Comment: @Brian See edit. And TMK with a serializer/deserializer it would mess up anything else that returns a JSONArray

Comment: You don't write one for a List/array - you write one for an object that contains a `build` field and a `List<MyObject>` field. Pass the list of parameters to `MyObject`'s constructor to instantiate each one and add it to the `List`. (I'm assuming each inner array in your JSON array represents the same type of object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example from comments above, but this is the line of thinking I'm trying to get at. Note I haven't tested this or anything but at the very least it should put you on the path if you wanted to go this route.

```
class OuterObject {
    String build;
    List<InnerObject> objectList = new ArrayList<InnerObject>();
}

class InnerObject {
    int field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8;

    public InnerObject(int[] params) {
        // assign params accordingly
    }
}

class MyDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<OuterObject> {
    @Override
    public OuterObject deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException
    {
        OuterObject oo = new OuterObject();
        JsonObject jo = je.getAsJsonObject();

        oo.build = jo.get("build").getAsString();
        JsonArray innerObjArrays =  jo.getAsJsonArray("list");
        for (JsonElement e : innerObjArrays)
        {
            JsonArray innerArray = e.getAsJsonArray();
            // This is ugly but should give you the gist
            InnerClass ic = new InnerClass((int[])jdc.deserialize(innerArray, int[].class));
            oo.objectList.add(ic);
        }

        return oo;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to tweak things a little bit (build should be `jo.get("build").getAsString()`) but you provided a great starting point